# How to find sentence on website?

Tags: python, find, web, html, urllib

I am trying to do some easy word/sentence finder.

Tried this:

```
import urllib
from urllib import request

url = "https://fotka.com/profil/k"
word = "Nie ma profilu"


def search_website(url, word):
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
phrase_present = False

for i in page:
    if bytes(word, encoding='utf8') in i:
        phrase_present = True
        print(i)

return phrase_present

finder = search_website(url, word)
print(finder)
```

Looks like it works fine BUT, explanation about `url`.
If you open in a browser:

```
url = "https://fotka.com/profil/k"
```

There is indeed searched `word` present so returns `True`, but if you open:

```
url = "https://fotka.com/profil/kkkk"
```

There is no such `word` on page and it still returns `True`.

I have checked content of variable `page` and in both cases it is the same while `url` is different...

Anyone knows why with any ideas for workaround?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "How to check is there visible test on the page?" then, this might be your solution for you

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "some page"
word = "some word"

page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

html = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print word in html.get_text()
```

Comment: I have changed content of my question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted a very broad cast, but I think you are looking for data between paragraph tags `<p>`:

```
import re
import urllib
url = "some page"
word = "some word"

page_data = str(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
paragraph_data = re.findall("<p>(.*?)</p>", page_data)
final_paragraph_data = [i for i in paragraph_data if word in i]
```

`final_paragraph_data` now stores a list of all the clusters of sentences that contains the contents of `word`.

Comment: you might also want to have a look at the `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL` flags

Comment: I have changed content of my question to be more understandable.